# is it right to use BecomeFirstResponder in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard, viewdidload, becomefirstresponder

I want to bring the keyboard up for a textfield when a viewcontroller is opened.

so I am calling *becomefirstresponder* on *textfield* and it always works.

But I wonder

1. Is it right place to call becomefirstresponder ? or do I have to call in some other life cycle event in viewcontroller
2. if view did load is the right place to call.. do I have to manually call in main thread or not required as by default view didload is required ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing absolutely wrong with what you're doing.

Logically one might argue that `viewDidLoad` is too soon, since your view (with your text field) is not in the interface; perhaps `viewDidAppear` would be a more logical place. In that case, though, you have to keep in mind that `viewDidAppear` can be called multiple times during the view controller's lifetime, so you'd need to distinguish whether this is the first time (not hard).

Comment: Thanks for answreing.I guess keeping it in ViewDidLoad is right thing to do .. I know viewDidload is main thread .. .do I have call inside main thread to be in safer side.